# Create an animation to pause at the specified location

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic, animation

[image]

How can I pause play at the specified location when export a gif file or using Animate?
I want it to run automatically, no need to interact with the mouse. Here is an example:

```
Clear[f];
f[t_] := With[{angles = {0, -30 , -90 , -120 , 180 } Degree},
  Graphics[{
    Thick, Circle[],
    {Yellow, Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, -t } + Pi/2]}, PointSize[Large], 
    Point[{0, 0}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, AngleVector[Pi/2 - t]}],
    Line[{AngleVector[#], AngleVector[#] 1.1}] & /@ angles,
    MapThread[
     Text, {{1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4}, 1.4 (AngleVector /@ angles)}]
    }, PlotRange -> 1.7]]

Animate[f[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
tlist = Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/180];
pauseat = {Pi/2, 2 Pi/3, Pi, 7 Pi/6, 3 Pi/2};
pausepos = Nearest[tlist -> Automatic, #] & /@ pauseat;
reps = 10;
tlist2 = Flatten[MapAt[ConstantArray[#, reps] &, tlist, pausepos]];
```

You can use `tlist2` in `Animate` iterator:

```
Animate[f[t], {t, tlist2}, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

or to generate a table of frames to be used in `ListAnimate`:

```
labeling = Thread[tlist[[Flatten @ pausepos]] -> {1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4}]; 

frames = Table[If[MemberQ[tlist[[Flatten @ pausepos]], t], 
   Replace[f[t], Text[txt : (t /. labeling), p_] :> 
     Text[Style[txt, 16, Blue, Bold], p], All], f[t]], 
  {t,  tlist2}];

ListAnimate[frames, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

Export `frames` as a `gif` file:

```
Export["stutteringclock.gif", frames]
```

[image]

A simpler alternative (but ... sometimes skips a stop):

```
pauseat = N @ {Pi/2, 2 Pi/3, Pi, 7 Pi/6, 3 Pi/2};
nF = Nearest[pauseat];

Animate[If[PossibleZeroQ[Chop[t - nF[t][[1]], Pi/620]], Pause[1]; f[t], f[t]], 
 {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/620}, DisplayAllSteps -> True, AnimationRate -> 100]
```

Answer (score 7):

What I’ve done in the past is something like `anim = Table[f[t], {t, 0, 2Pi, 0.01}]` and then `Export[“anim.gif”, anim, ImageResolution -> 300, “DisplayDurations” -> listOfTimes]`, where `listOfTimes` is generated so that most frames have the same display duration, but the frames of interest have a much longer display duration.